# I have had wheel alignment and balancing several times, still my car is shaking

Tags: alignment, shaking

I have had wheel rotation, wheel alignment and balancing for my car several times at different service stations, still my car is shaking. Steering is also shaking.
What could be the reason for this?

I have noticed that when I reach beyond 90 Km/h, this shaking effect goes away.

I had a talk with the service engineer, he advised me two things:

1. Replace spindle.
2. Replace all the old wheels with new.

I had the spindle replacement done for my car still the issue persists.
I am not sure if the shaking will go or not by replacing all the old wheels.
What should I do?

Comment: What car do you have?

Comment: Fiat Punto - Emotion 1.2 Fire (petrol)

Comment: If your wheels were balanced, I'm not sure why replacing them would be suggested...

Comment: Has it always been shaking or did it start suddenly? if so, when?

Comment: It all started after my car was smashed by a another car driver from behind, right on to the left rear corner of my car. Due to this my service engineer doubted the spindle and I had it get replaced. But still the issue persist.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It could very well be that the tires are misformed due to ply separation, this is not very rare on old tires. It would make the wheel take a form that is not round, and you will get vibrations even if the wheels are perfectly in balance. since the steering wheel is vibrating, it probably is a front tire, so you could get by with changing two of your wheels. (keep the best pair on your rear axle)

If you want to test this you could try switching the front tires with the rear to see if the shaking in the steering wheel disappears. (Your car would still vibrate though)

Also, visually inspect the wheels to see if there is any damage to it. It's not always as apparent as this, but it can often be seen when looking at the wheel.

[image: ply separation]

Comment: Thanks @Allman, I am very much delighted with the information you shared. I will definitely try what you have suggested.

Comment: great! Let us know how it goes =)

Comment: I consulted my mechanic and agreed to change tires. We discussed upon problems with the tires by closely looking at all of them one by one. Finally found a tire which was problematic. I purchased only one new tire and replaced with the problematic one. It helped me solve my issue. Thanks Allman, I am extremely delighted.